# Junction table in one-to-many relationship?

Tags: mysql

I have a question regarding junction tables and I really hope you can help me out as it is confusing me. I know that junction tables are usually implemented to create two one-to-many relationships instead of one many-to-many, but see the example below:

In a hypothetical situation where a user can have multiple photos (like a portfolio) but there are also groups that can have multiple photos.

The situation would look something like this I believe (please correct me if I'm already wrong here):
[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLMxE.jpg)

But isn't it preferable to create a situation using junctions tables like the image below: 
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBzqC.jpg)

In this way you prevent the Photo table from getting alot of NULL values, assuming you set the two foreign keys, User_ID and Group_ID, to NOT NULL.

Thank you for your time and I hope someone could guide me with this.

Comment: Can a photo belong in multiple groups or have different users? Are those groups really just user aggregations?

Comment: To add to what @brunch875 stated, and maybe go where they are heading, you could make every user have their own (possibly hidden) personal group.

Comment: Hello Brunch875. Users can join more than one group and a group can have more than one user. Because this is a many-to-many relationship I have created a junction table User_Groups with both primary keys as foreign keys in the junction table. I have not shown this in the screenshot however. In this case I would like to use an example in which a photo can belong in multiple groups or users.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have done... I create a relator table that has three columns

leftsideID, relatortype, RightSideID

In your case.. you have two relationship types that connect photos to things.
Users and groups.

So I would have two relatortypes   USERPHOTO and GROUPPHOTO.
All the RightSideID's point to photo keys in the photo table.

All leftside ID's either carry the userid or the groupid, based upon the relator type, example could be:

```
leftsideid    relatortpype    rightside
==========    ============    =========
1             'userphoto'       1
2             'groupphoto'      1
1             'userphoto'       2
```

This says (in three rows), that user1 has two photos(1,2) and group2 has photo(1)

no nulls.   I have used design pattern alot to a high degree of success.

Its basically a generic Junction Table, given your example.

---